# Python - Count JSON elements before extracting data

Tags: python, json

I use an API which gives me a JSON file structured like this:

```
{
offset: 0,
results: [
{
  source_link: "http://www.example.com/1",
  source_link/_title: "Title example 1",
  source_link/_source: "/1",
  source_link/_text: "Title example 1"
},
{
  source_link: "http://www.example.com/2",
  source_link/_title: "Title example 2",
  source_link/_source: "/2",
  source_link/_text: "Title example 2"
},
...
```

And I use this code in Python to extract the data I need:

```
import json
import urllib2

u = urllib2.urlopen('myapiurl')
z = json.load(u)
u.close
link = z['results'][1]['source_link']
title = z['results'][1]['source_link/_title']
```

The problem is that to use it I have to know the number of the element from which I'm extracting the data. My `results` can have different length every time, so what I want to do is to count the number of elements in `results` at first, so I would be able to set up a loop to extract data from each element.

Comment: `len(z["results"])` is surely all you need? That'll give you the length. But with `for` loops the length isn't needed, so just use that.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To check the length of the results key:

```
len(z["results"])
```

But if you're just looping around them, a for loop is perfect:

```
for result in x["results"]:
    print(result["source_link"])
```

Answer (score 3):

You didn't need to know the length of the result, you are fine with a for loop:

```
for result in z['results']:
    # process the results here
```

Anyway, if you want to know the length of 'results': `len(z.results)`

Comment: Well, in python that would be `z['results']`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the length, you can try:

```
len(z['result'])
```

But in python, what we usually do is:

```
for i in z['result']:
    # do whatever you like with `i`
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Agh! I was about 3 seconds late!

Answer (score 1):

You don't need, or likely want, to count them in order to loop over them, you could do:

```
import json
import urllib2

u = urllib2.urlopen('myapiurl')
z = json.load(u)
u.close
for result in z['results']:
    link = result['source_link']
    title = result['source_link/_title']
    # do something with link/title
```

Or you could do:

```
u = urllib2.urlopen('myapiurl')
z = json.load(u)
u.close
link = [result['source_link'] for result in z['results']]
title = [result['source_link/_title'] for result in z['results']]
# do something with links/titles lists
```

Answer (score 1):

Few pointers:

1. No need to know `results`'s length to iterate it. You can use `for result in z['results']`.
2. `list`s start from `0`.
3. If you do need the index take a look at [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Answer (score 0):

use this command to print the result on the terminal and then can check the number of results

```
print(len(z['results'][0]))
```